# Best way to concatenate subarrays along an axis?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of arrays:
`a = [ [[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]] ]`

How can I, for each subarray in the above array, perform the following:

1. reshape(-1,1)
2. concatenate along axis=1

`a` is not a numpy array but it can of course be converted to a numpy array. I do not care whether it stays a Python list or is converted to a numpy array - whatever yields the most concise/clean solution.

I am aware that this can be accomplished using a for loop but it seems clumsy and I am interesting in cleaner solutions :)

The result I expect is:

`[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]`

Comment: Can you add how should be the expected output from the input sample you gave?

Comment: use np.concatenate

Comment: @yannziselman that is only valid when there are two subarrays. When there are more subarrays, it becomes clumsy as I mentioned :)

Comment: @lucascavalcante Of course! 2 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to reshape each sub-array to `(-1, 1)`, which means the overall shape of the initial array is `(len(a), -1, 1)`. From there we can [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) on `axis=1`:

```
>>> a
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])

>>> a.reshape((len(a), -1, 1))
array([[[1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]],

       [[5],
        [6],
        [7],
        [8]]])

>>> np.concatenate(x.reshape((len(x), -1, 1)), 1)
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 8]])
```

*Note: `len(a)` is essentially `a.shape[0]`*

---

Alternatively you can discard the last axis and work with [`np.stack`](http://c) instead:

```
>>> np.stack(x.reshape((len(x), -1)), 1)
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 8]])
```

Comment: Uhh, i'll test it in a minute, thanks! Does this also work when there are 3+ subarrays instead of just 2?

Comment: It will work with any number of sub-arrays... as long as you use `len(a)` when reshaping of course.

Answer (score 1):

The library [einops](https://pypi.org/project/einops/) contains a function `rearrange` that should do the trick in a tidy manner. It uses the same type of indexing as `np.einsum` to operate flexible reshaping operations.

```
import numpy as np
a = [ [[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]] ]
an = np.array(a)

from einops import rearrange

ar = rearrange(an, "a b c -> (b c) a")
ar
```

output:

```
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A python list solution:

```
In [182]: alist = []
     ...: for xy in zip(*a):
     ...:     alist.extend(list(zip(*xy)))
     ...: 
In [183]: alist
Out[183]: [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```